# Apache 2.4+ Conditional SSI Syntax

Tags: apache, ssi

I have enabled the SSILegacyExprParser on within the directory and this works....however..I am trying to get an understanding of correct syntax without using the backward compatible Legacy Parser.

I have this written the old way prior to Apache 2.4

```
<!--#if expr="$lftNav = On && $rtNav = Off"-->
    link to files here
<!--#endif-->
```

And I rewrote it to this

```
<!--#if expr="v('lftNav') = 'On' && v('rtNav') = 'Off'"-->
    link to files here
<!--#endif-->
```

However I can't seem to get this to work correctly.  Do I have the syntax correct?  Can anyone point me to an example page?  The documentation for Apache 2.4 isn't really helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok...I figured out my issue.  I had to re-write it this way to get it to work in Apache 2.4

```
<!--#set var="lftNav" value="On"-->
<!--#set var="rtNav" value="Off"-->

<!--#if expr="(v('lftNav') = 'On') && (v('rtNav') = 'Off')"-->
    link to files here
<!--#endif-->
```

In case anyone else was having trouble.  I was in the right ballpark.....I just needed to surround each expression in ()